# how i can get resolve with the duplicate title in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, rest, duplicates, meanjs

here i am getting the error message called "duplicate title" in the body itself from the server side. but my problem is, in this example the title length should be 24 characters. But if the title is alredy present then it displays an error message.

but what my requirement is, if it is the duplicate title after we enter the next letter the duplicate message will need to be disappeared...

here is the code for that...

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <form name="taskForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="create()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">
                    <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control place" ng-model="title" id="title" placeholder="Enter Task Timer Here">
                    <span ng-show="duplicateTitle" class="text-danger">Duplicate Task Title. Please choose Unique Title!</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <span ng-click="create()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus plusIcon"></span>
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

controllers file is...

```
$scope.create = function () {
            var currentDate = new Date();

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tasks.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.tasks[i].title === this.title) {
                    $scope.duplicateTitle = true;

                    console.log("duplictae" + $scope.duplicateTitle);
                    return;
                }
            }


            var task = new Tasks({
                'title': this.title,
                'description': this.description,
                'duration': 0,
//              'lastStart': currentDate
            });

            task.$save(function (response) {
                //$location.path('tasks');
                $scope.duplicateTitle = false;
                //$scope.tasks.push(response);
                $scope.tasks = Tasks.query();
                $scope.title = '';
                $scope.description = '';
            }, function (errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `ng-change="duplicateTitle = false"` attribute to the input. This will clear the error message after input has changed.